# Whether to appear in the group by clause OR be used in an aggregate function?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I am joining two tables, and grouping by a column that has no duplicates in one table (although it may link with multiple rows in the other table). If I also select other columns of this table then I am required to list them in the group by clause, or apply aggregation functions.

```
select A.id, A.x, A.y, max(B.z) 
from A join B on A.id = B.id_ref
group by A.id
```

This creates an error: the extra columns (`A.x, A.y`) must be listed in the group by clause, or wrapped in aggregate functions (such as `max`). *Both options will produce identical results* because the `id` field has no duplicates in table `A` (for example, it may be a row id or a primary key).

Is there any convention about which option I should prefer? (Or is there a better alternative such as `distinct on` or nested subqueries?? Note that I do still wish to perform a proper aggregation on the column from the other table, `B.z`.) For example, will adding a text column (`A.y`) to the group-by slow down the query? Or which aggregation function will have the least performance cost and most readability?

Answer (score 1):

> ... the id field has no duplicates in table A (for example, it may be a row id or a primary key).

If `id` **is a primary key**, Postgres allows to skip the other columns of the table in `group by` clause, see [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0c68e/1)

If `id` is not a primary key, you should list the remaining columns in `group by` clause. It's more natural and often more efficient way than placing them in an aggregate.